# Grails Cache and EHCache Plugin caches Controller methods but not Service methods

Tags: grails, caching, plugins, ehcache, grails-2.0

I'm having trouble getting the Grails EHCache Plugin to cache service methods. Here is my setup:

Grails 2.4.2, JDK 1.7

BuildConfig.groovy `compile ":cache-ehcache:1.0.4"`

Config.groovy defines the following cache named "cache"

```
grails.cache.config = {
    cache {
        name 'cache'
        timeToLiveSeconds 60
    }
}
```

The following controller method properly caches. I have tested by setting a breakpoint in the method, and it only is hit the first time, until the cache expires.

```
@Cacheable('cache')
def index() {
    render "index-$params.id"
}
```

I can check the keys in the cache with:

`grailsCacheManager.getCache('cache').getNativeCache().getKeys()`

and see the value:

`localhost:GET:/grails-cache-test/cache/index?id=34`

So far so good.

The following service method exists:

```
@Cacheable('cache')
public method1(id) {
    "method1+$id"
}
```

I set a break point in here, and this method is always called, regardless of the `@Cacheable` annotation. I've tried setting the `value` and `key` annotation attributes manually, and no change. I test calling this method from a non-cached controller method, as well as directly from the console plugin. When I get the keys in the service method I see that there are no keys set.

I've looked through examples in the official documentation, code samples online, github, a book I have, everything looks good, so I'm not sure where the problem lies.

Any ideas on why this service method does not cache the value? Thanks!

**UPDATE 1**

I've been digging into the grails cache-1.1.8 plugin (as well as the associated cache-ehcache-1.0.4 plugin), and believe I've found something helpful. In `PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter()` there are calls to check the *controller's* annotations - but nothing to check the service. It appears that as a result, the service annotations are never honored. There is a lot of documentation that mentions service methods, so I don't know if there is something elsewhere that handles this, or if it's a less common use case compared to controller methods.

**UPDATE 2**

It appears that Controllers and Services are handled separately. In `CacheAspectSupport.execute()` there is a `for()` loop that will call `cachePutRequest.apply(result.get());`, which will actually add the entry to the cache. Unfortunately after the entry is added to the request, it is not immediately available to be retrieved. The underlying `put()` code is part of Spring Source, so at this point I'm not sure if it's a grails plugin issue or a Spring Source issue.

I have created a JIRA issue for this plugin [GPCACHEEHCACHE-16](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GPCACHEEHCACHE-16)

Comment: Though probably not very helpful to you, we are using ehcache on service methods in a production application and it's working as it is supposed to (ehcache 1.0.0, Grails 2.3.6)

Comment: @GregorPetrin I do appreciate the comment, thank you. I know there were some big changes going from Grails 2.3 to 2.4, so I'm wondering if there is a regression in the functionality of this plugin. I'll try creating a Grails 2.3 application to test this out.

Comment: Cool, please post the results here, I would be interested in them!

Comment: Just finished some simple testing, here is what I found: Grails 2.3.6 works with ehcache plugin 1.0.0, but fails with 1.0.1. Grails 2.4.2 has build failures for ehcache plugin 1.0.0 and 1.0.1, it build with 1.0.2, but the cache is broken.